# Accurev Merge GUI from CLI command

Tags: version-control, merge, diff, accurev

Is there any CLI command that can be used to open Accurev Merge window from command line. Assume, I have already logged into Accurev.

I analysed, and understood till these commands

`accurev guimerge` - to get file's most recent version, merging version and common ancestor version.

`accurev cat` - to get the contents of a version of an element.

But, using these, I am not sure what is the command that can show the merge window so that user can merge the files manually.

I know that `accurev merge` command can display the result in command line. But, I am looking for the Accurev merge GUI to open up for me. I am sure this can be achieved but don't know how to proceed.

I can see there are tools like acdiffgui.exe in my accurev installation directory. Can I use it somehow to display Accurev Merge window?

Also, one more point is, I donot want to change Accurev preferences on the user's machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the -G option with the merge command.

From the CLI manual under section merge:

-G - Use AccuRev’s graphical Merge tool to perform the merge if there are conflicts which require human interaction (any value set in AC_MERGE_CLI is ignored).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot.